# Meaning of ${${arg}} in CMake?

Tags: cmake

I am looking for an explanation of the following function in CMake:

```
function(file_grab src arg)
file(GLOB_RECURSE ${arg} CONFIGURE_DEPENDS
 ${src}/*.cc
 ${src}/*.hpp
)
set(${arg} ${${arg}} PARENT_SCOPE)
endfunction(file_grab)
```

As far as I understand, we use `filesystem` and recursively grab all the files with `*.cc` and `*.hpp` extension and set it to `arg` variable.
What I don't understand is

```
set(${arg} ${${arg}} PARENT_SCOPE)
```

I understand the first argument is to set whatever `${${arg}}` is to the `arg` variable in `PARENT_SCOPE`. What does the nested `${${arg}}`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`${${arg}}` is a *nested variable reference*, see [variable references](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-language.7.html#variable-references).

As explained in the documentation, it is evaluated from the inside out. In your case, the value of `${arg}` is used as a variable name and itself evaluated.

#### Example

```
set(foo "42")
set(arg "foo")
message(STATUS "${${arg}}")
```

will print `42`.

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I was looking for.